# How to replace text in large XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, streamreader

When I tryto remove text in an xml file, ie. rsquo, I get a 'System.OutOfMemoryException' exception error.

Any advice? - Its written in vb

```
   <Person>
   <Name>&rsquo; John /&rsquo; </Name>
   <age> 24 </age>
   <DOB>
      <year> 1990 </year>
      <month> 03 </month>
      <date> 23 </date>
  </DOB>
</Person>

   Dim myStreamReaderL1 As StreamReader
   Dim myStream As StreamWriter
   Dim mystr As String

   myStreamReaderL1 = System.IO.File.OpenText(Server.MapPath( filepath_Label.Text))
   myStr = myStreamReaderL1.ReadToEnd() 
   myStreamReaderL1.Close()

   If mystr.Contains("&rsquo;") Then
     mystr = mystr.Replace("&rsquo;", "")
     count += count + 1
    End If

    myStream = System.IO.File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("Valedate/" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "/new" & TextBox_filename.Text))
    myStream.WriteLine(myStr)
    myStream.Close()
```

Comment: How big is the file, and does this happen to be in a loop? You could try processing line by line. It might be a little slower, but you shouldn't run out of memory.

Comment: Something to think about: consider using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) when working with XML.

Comment: The file is 92.7 MB - will try line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your mistake:

```
myStr = myStreamReaderL1.ReadToEnd()
```

You only need `ReadToEnd()` if you need repeated nonsequential access to widely-separated positions in your file. If you are doing that you should not be using a `StreamReader`. You should not use `ReadToEnd()` to perform sequential access, like replacing a string on every line. Do something like this:

```
Using sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(filepath_Label.Text))
Using sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("Valedate/" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "/new" & TextBox_filename.Text))
    Dim l As String
    l = sr.ReadLine
    Do While (Not l Is Nothing)
        If l.Contains("&rsquo;") Then
            l = l.Replace("&rsquo;", "")
        End If

        sw.WriteLine(l)
        l = sr.ReadLine
    End While
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you! - It worked! only think I can't count the amount of changes and Do While ... Loop.

Comment: You can count the amount of changes inside the `If` block.

Comment: I did, I got this error: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. - System.OverflowException

Comment: @user3366527, you have to post the code that's giving you the error because I can't see your screen.

Comment: I fixed it ! I had count += count + 1 when it should be count += 1

Answer (score 0):

The character sequence `&rsquo;` is the **HTML Entity (named)** for the [Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).

The entity `&rsquo;` isn't actually allowed in XML without first declaring it:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE section [ 
  <!ENTITY rsquo '&#x2019;'> 
]>
```

When it comes to working with XML files, you generally *shouldn't do so as plain text*. Instead, you should choose a specialized library designed for working with XML. Microsoft lists a number of approaches in its article [XML Processing Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669131%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Under the heading **.NET Framework Options**, Microsoft says for **LINQ To XML**, "Use this option if you're writing new code."

With that in mind, I've written a short program in **C#** to demonstrate a possible approach for you. (I'm hoping you can translate the concepts to **VB**.) Below, you'll find the expected output from the program following by the program itself.

**Expected Output**

```xml
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <Name> John / </Name>
    <age> 24 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1990 </year>
      <month> 03 </month>
      <date> 23 </date>
    </DOB>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name> Jane / </Name>
    <age> 21 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1993 </year>
      <month> 04 </month>
      <date> 25 </date>
    </DOB>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

**Example Program**

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class LinqToXmlDemo
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(GetXml());

        // Define a LINQ to XML query to return an enumeration of the
        // `Name` elements. (Those are the elements whose values you
        // wish to edit.)
        var query =
            from name in document.Root.Elements("Person").Elements("Name")
            select name;

        // The character that you want to remove.
        string s = Convert.ToChar(0x2019).ToString();

        // Iterate through each of the `Name` elements returned by the
        // query and remove the character of interest.
        foreach (var name in query)
        {
            if (name != null)
            {
                name.Value = ((string)name).Replace(s, String.Empty);
            }
        }

        // Output the edited document.
        Console.WriteLine(document.Root.ToString());
    }

    static string GetXml()
    {
        return
            @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
              <!DOCTYPE section [ 
                <!ENTITY rsquo '&#x2019;'> 
              ]>
              <Persons>
                <Person>
                  <Name>&rsquo; John /&rsquo; </Name>
                  <age> 24 </age>
                  <DOB>
                     <year> 1990 </year>
                     <month> 03 </month>
                     <date> 23 </date>
                  </DOB>
                </Person>
                <Person>
                  <Name>&rsquo; Jane /&rsquo; </Name>
                  <age> 21 </age>
                  <DOB>
                     <year> 1993 </year>
                     <month> 04 </month>
                     <date> 25 </date>
                  </DOB>
                </Person>
              </Persons>";
    }
}
```